# IPad top nav bar - hidden then activated by button (like tap screen, but using a single button)

Tags: ios, ipad, user-interface

I want my top nav bar to be hidden, with a menu icon in the top left hand corner (same position as on the nav bar). When the button is activated the top nav bar appears and the menu icon appears in the same position on the nav bar. So the top nav bar show hides like the tap screen function, but rather than tapping anywhere on the screen its on a specific button. Is this possible? (i'm a designer not a developer btw)

Comment: Your objective is not really clear from the question. Add some illustrations maybe?

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: yeah it's possible but it doesn't seems to be a good approach.

Comment: Isn't it just a straight case of adding a tap event to the button and calling: self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO; or am I not understanding something? Maybe you wanted to make it fade in and out like the photo gallery app ?